# g.i.cs class keeps changing its base class back to its default

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

g.i.cs class keeps changing its base class back to its default

```
System.Windows.Controls.Page
```

After I've changed it to

```
System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
```

I need it to be a UserControl because the other partial class' base class is a UserControl

After compiling I get the message

> "...file.g.i.cs This file has been modified outside of the source
>   editor.  Do you want to reload it?"

If I say no, I can compile, but after a while, it switches back again.  If I choose yes, it instantly switches back.

Any ideas?

Oh, and no one else is working on the files :-)

Comment: You shouldn't have the `.g.i.cs` files open or part of your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didn't find the solution, but I found out why it happens in the first place.  When adding the Silver Light file, I chose 'Silverlight Page'.  I should have chosen 'Silverlight User Control'.  I guess once you choose one, you can't turn it into the other...  Hope this helps someone eventually lol.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the beginning of your XAML.  You will see a tag that opens with ... change that to  and then do the same for the closing tag at the bottom.

You may also have to update your code behind file to make sure the class it defines isn't explicitly derived from the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

The file is constantly changing because it is a generated file. this indicates the g in the name. To change a WPF view's base class you have to change it either in the code behind file as well as in WPF itself.

To change it in WPF, you can use the Class attribute:

```
x:Class="Name.Space.ClassName"
```

Comment: When you're referring to WPF, would that be my silver light file (.xaml)?  I've already changed the code behind file, and that seems to stick.  It's just the g.i.cs file that I'm having issues with...

Comment: Yes, i mean the file where you have written your xaml.

Comment: That class value was already set to the proper value (code behind file[class]).  I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Close but not quite... it's the opening tag of the XAML that determines this

Comment: Yeah, right. The class tag is used to determine the class that contains the code behind. It is the opening node type that has to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a WPF project, then you need to change window attributes in the XAML file.. in my case I had to change the `x:class` and `xmlns:local`.
good luck! :)